# to unserialize data is it necessary to have the same array structure from which it save in to database

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I used a component of Joomla for CCKT, it store data after serialize() it,

on the other side I am using another component for generating csv & xls file which convert all the sql data in to csv.

so when i call those data which are stored in db as a serialise it shows in xls also as a serialise & **i want them unserialise**

***so the question is it necessary that the component which generate xls & csv should know the array of the serialise to convert it in un-serialise..??***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

PHP serialize creates a string.

CSV generators usually loop through an array for the values, but the DB query returns a string for the serialized value.

Use unserialize() to re-build the serialized array and pass it over to your CSV function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Check the PHP documentation and what the CSV function accepts as parameters.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No, it doesn't. XLS has a complicated structure compared to CSV.